# How to insert 2 controls, one into each different column in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls

I place 10 or 15 webcontrols into 2 columns int a gridview dynamically.

So say if i decide to add 15 controls , then i want 15 of them to appear at each row of the two columns..

I want paging to be enabled as well.

How do i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the following code to add the controls.  
The following code adds a textbox to the 2nd Cell in every row including the footer row.

```
    protected void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
            tbox = "the text you wasnt to add or bind with data field"; 
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(tbox);
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
            tbox = "the text you wasnt to add or bind with data field"; 
            e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(tbox);
        }
    }
```